# How to restrict the access to a folder to users in specific roles

Tags: .net, security, web-config

I've been trying to use the following code inside a web.config, that is inside the folder i want to have restricted access but without success, because every user with the path to the file can access it, anyone knows what is wrong?

the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization> 
        <allow roles="Administrador, Executivo, Publico" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>    
</configuration>
```

is inside the folder "Uploads"

I'm using forms authentication and it's configured in the main web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

May this be a IIS configuration problem? Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code for web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization> 
        <allow roles="Administrador, Executivo, Publico" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>     
  </configuration>
```

Comment: It makes no difference

Comment: it's different in <deny users="*" />

Comment: What i mean is that it's still not preventing any type of user to access the folder.

Comment: It seems like that web.config is doing absolutly nothing there